# Find the remainder attained by dividing the polynomial $x^{2019}-2x^{1992}+x^{1965}+x^{55}+2x^{28}+x^5+2019$ by $(x^{18}+x^9+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Find the remainder attained by dividing the polynomial $x^{2019}-2x^{1992}+x^{1965}+x^{55}+2x^{28}+x^5+2019$ by $(x^{18}+x^9+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$

I honestly don't know how to start this problem without trying to use long division. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: note that the divisor times $x^3-1$ equals $x^{27}-1$. Do you find it easier to find the remainder when dividing by $x^{27}-1$? Can you get from there to the final answer?

Comment: Since $y^2 + y + 1 = \frac{y^3 - 1}{y - 1}$, try substituting $y = x^{9}$ and $y = x^{3}$. When you do this, apply it to your divisor & simplify, you'll get what Greg Martin's comment says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Greg Martin noted, we can expand to find
$$\left(x^6+x^3+1\right) \left(x^{18}+x^9+1\right)=x^{24}+x^{21}+x^{18}+x^{15}+x^{12}+x^9+x^6+x^3+1.$$
Notice that this is the geometric sum $\sum_{i=0}^8 x^{3i}=\frac{1-x^{27}}{1-x^3}$, and thus
$$\left(x^6+x^3+1\right) \left(x^{18}+x^9+1\right)(1-x^3)=1-x^{27}.$$

In the ring $\Bbb Z[x]$, consider the ideal $I=\left(\left(x^6+x^3+1\right) \left(x^{18}+x^9+1\right)\right)$. We have seen that $I$ contains $1-x^{27}$, so in $\Bbb Z[x]/I$, $x^{27}=1$. In the quotient,

$$x^{2019}-2x^{1992}+x^{1965}+x^{55}+2x^{28}+x^5+2019$$
becomes
$$x^{21}-2x^{21}+x^{21}+x+2x+x^5+2019=x^5+3x+2019.$$

Comment: Wow! This solution is exquisite. Thank you sir so much.